# CORS error: Preflight request succeeds, subsequent GET request fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I've built a web application with Angular and ASP.NET Core 3.1. After introducing a new API controller with GET actions only, requests to this controller running into CORS error ("CORS Missing Allow Origin"). The weird thing is, that requests to other controllers in the application do not issue CORS errors. I tried with several browsers, but all ended in the same error.

Even when I take a look at the [preflight request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxZ3p.png) in Firefox, everything just looks fine. The returned "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"-Header matches the "Origin"-Header of the request. But with the subsequent [GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syCuk.png), server returns 302.

I added a proper CORS configuration in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicyName,
        builder =>
        {
            builder
                .WithOrigins(*my allowed origins*)
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .WithExposedHeaders("location", "content-disposition")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});
```

And also added the according middleware in `Startup.Configure`:

```
app.UseCors(CorsPolicyName);
```

Can anyone give me a clue what is going wrong here?

Comment: please provide the code definition of your controller and action that is no working (with also the data annotations)

Comment: Is the 302 relevant to the request? Is it an error page? etc.

Comment: Alright, the problem could be solved. There is a setting in our web application firewall where new routes have to be explicitly granted.

Answer (score 0):

At first, install NuGet Package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` and run your project. if not work, then try the below process.

I think it's should work fine.

`Startup.ConfigureServices`

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

{
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            });

        //clarify code

}
```

`Startup.Configure`

```
 app.UseCors(x => 
  x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200")); //your client URL
```